# Java8 Null-safe comparison

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

Having issues with comparing two products. I wish to compare the vintage (which is optional) attribute of each of them. But whenever this attribute is null, a NPE is thrown. I thought with Comparator.nullsLast(..) I can deal with null values... But it seems I either have a misunderstanding of how this works or there's something wrong with the code. What do I need to change to get this work null-friendly?

```
@Override
public int compare(IProduct product1, IProduct product2) throws ProductComparisonException {

    Comparator<IShopProduct> comparator =
        Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(IShopProduct::getVintage));

    return comparator.compare((IShopProduct)product1.getProvidedProductData(),
                              (IShopProduct)product2.getProvidedProductData());
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there a chance that `product1.getProvidedProductData()` returns null ?

Comment: Please look over the standard java style guide. People will be more likely to help you if they aren't distracted by idiosyncratic styling issues. In particular, the unnecessary spaces and the fact that the line is so long I have to scroll horizontally

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be

```
Comparator<IShopProduct> comparator = 
            Comparator.comparing( IShopProduct::getVintage, 
                             Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

`Comparator.nullsFirst()/nullsLast()` consider null value being greater/smaller than nonNull object

**Edit**

This is implementation of Comparator.comparing():

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
    return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
        (c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
}
```

As you can see it calls `keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo()` so it will throw NPE if `keyExtractor.apply(c1)` is `null`

My suggested code using the following function:

```
public static <T, U> Comparator<T> comparing(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor,
        Comparator<? super U> keyComparator)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyComparator);
    return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
        (c1, c2) -> keyComparator.compare(keyExtractor.apply(c1),
                                          keyExtractor.apply(c2));
}
```

Basically it will extracts the value, then pass the comparing values to `Comparator`.

The values will be passed to the `naturalOrder()` comparator which resolved to `value1.compareTo(value2)`. Normally it will throw NPE but we have wrapped it with `Comparator.nullsLast` which have special `null` handler.

Comment: Thanks! Why exactly do I need the naturalOrder as a second param?

Answer (score 4):

This overload of the [comparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) method will throw an exception if the passed in key extractor function is `null` or the property extracted is `null`. Since, you mentioned the `vintage` property can be `null` at times then this is the cause of the NullPointerException.

An alternative, to overcome the problem is to use this comparator:

```
 Comparator<IShopProduct> comparator = 
      Comparator.comparing(IShopProduct::getVintage,
                Comparator.nullsLast(naturalOrder()));
```

The key extractor i.e `IShopProduct::getVintage` is the function used to extract the sort key.

The key comparator i.e. the `Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())` is used to compare the sort key.

`Comparator.naturalOrder()` here simply returns a comparator that compares `Comparable` objects in natural order.